# Subsetting specific columns and rows from a data.frame - error message "unexpected symbol in..."

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset, tibble

I'm a beginner learning how to subset specific rows and columns from a dataset in R. I am using the state.x77 dataset in R Studio as practice. When I try to select specified columns, I get the following error message:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

select(state.x77, Income, HS Grad)
Error: unexpected symbol in "select(state.x77, Income, HS Grad"
```

I do not understand what symbol in that line of code is not correct.

Also, if I am trying to filter a certain state in addition to selecting certain columns (variables), how do I use the filter function when the list of states is the row names? When I try:

```
rownames_to_column(state.x77, var = "State")
```

it creates a column called State for the state names but it does not seem to be permanent when I go to view state.x77 (and thus I can't use the filter function).

I am sorry, I am very much a beginner. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. First, `state.x77` is a matrix, so you need to convert it to a data frame because `select` function from the `dplyr` package only takes data frame as the first argument. Second, if there are spaces in the column names, it is necessary to use `` or "" to enclose the column name.

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)

# Show the class of state.x77
class(state.x77)
# [1] "matrix"

# Convert state.x77 to a data frame
state.x77_df <- as.data.frame(state.x77)

# Show the class of state.x77_df
class(state.x77_df)
[1] "data.frame"

# Select Income and `HS Grad` columns
# All the following will work
select(state.x77_df, Income, `HS Grad`)
select(state.x77_df, "Income", "HS Grad")
select(state.x77_df, c("Income", "HS Grad"))
```

For your second question, you have to save the output back to the object as follows.

```
library(tibble)

state.x77_df <- rownames_to_column(state.x77_df,  var = "State")
head(state.x77_df) 
       State Population Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad Frost   Area
1    Alabama       3615   3624        2.1    69.05   15.1    41.3    20  50708
2     Alaska        365   6315        1.5    69.31   11.3    66.7   152 566432
3    Arizona       2212   4530        1.8    70.55    7.8    58.1    15 113417
4   Arkansas       2110   3378        1.9    70.66   10.1    39.9    65  51945
5 California      21198   5114        1.1    71.71   10.3    62.6    20 156361
6   Colorado       2541   4884        0.7    72.06    6.8    63.9   166 103766
```

Comment: @jp334 I am glad to help. Please accept this post as the answer if you think this is helpful for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Convert state.x77 into a dataframe and renaming rowname into State column
df <- tibble::rownames_to_column(data.frame(state.x77), var = "State")

## You can select any columns by their column names or by index
# by column names
 col_names <- c("Income", "HS.Grad")
 df[,col_names]

# by column index
 col_index <- c(3,7)
 df[, col_index]

# Filtering(subsetting) data by state
subset(df, df$State == "Arizona")

 State   Population Income  Illiteracy  Life.Exp Murder HS.Grad  Frost  Area
Arizona       2212   4530        1.8    70.55     7.8    58.1     15   113417
```